# Carriage return '\r' stops working when pwntools are imported in python3

Tags: python, carriage-return, pwntools

I have this little method to print overlapping strings of 80 characters:

```
def print80(s):
    pad = ' '*(80-len(s))
    print((s+pad)[:80], end='\r')
```

It works well, but if I import [`pwntools`](http://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/), for example with `import pwn`, it stops working: the `\r` character is no longer printed.